# How t display mysql data in Table with datewise

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show machine maintenance table in my project ,currently i'm displaying all the data in single table, but now i want to display table in date wise .

```
SELECT * ,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') as groupdate,SUM(operationtime) as usetime  FROM `logusages` WHERE machineid = '$id' GROUP BY groupdate,empCode"
```

Output of Query =

```
Array
(
    [workingLogs] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 13
                    [key] => 5BTIB4EoklT6dVfTUR4ezwb8T3xdeTAi
                    [machineid] => HIT232300
                    [empCode] => 1003
                    [employeeid] => Jon Doe
                    [date] => 2016-03-21 09:27:33
                    [time] => 11:22:00
                    [operationtime] => 1800
                    [groupdate] => 2016-03-21
                    [usetime] => 1800
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [key] => 5BTIB4EoklT6dVfTUR4ezwb8T3xdeTAi
                    [machineid] => HIT232300
                    [empCode] => 1003
                    [employeeid] => Jon Doe
                    [date] => 2016-03-22 09:27:33
                    [time] => 11:22:00
                    [operationtime] => 1800
                    [groupdate] => 2016-03-22
                    [usetime] => 1800
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [key] => 5BTIB4EoklT6dVfTUR4ezwb8T3xdeTAi
                    [machineid] => HIT232300
                    [empCode] => 1004
                    [employeeid] => Jon Doe
                    [date] => 2016-03-22 09:27:33
                    [time] => 11:22:00
                    [operationtime] => 1800
                    [groupdate] => 2016-03-22
                    [usetime] => 1800
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [key] => 5BTIB4EoklT6dVfTUR4ezwb8T3xdeTAi
                    [machineid] => HIT232300
                    [empCode] => 1003
                    [employeeid] => Jon Doe
                    [date] => 2016-03-23 09:27:33
                    [time] => 11:22:00
                    [operationtime] => 1800
                    [groupdate] => 2016-03-23
                    [usetime] => 3600
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [key] => 5BTIB4EoklT6dVfTUR4ezwb8T3xdeTAi
                    [machineid] => HIT232300
                    [empCode] => 1004
                    [employeeid] => Jon Doe
                    [date] => 2016-03-23 09:27:33
                    [time] => 11:22:00
                    [operationtime] => 1800
                    [groupdate] => 2016-03-23
                    [usetime] => 3600
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [key] => 5BTIB4EoklT6dVfTUR4ezwb8T3xdeTAi
                    [machineid] => HIT232300
                    [empCode] => 1003
                    [employeeid] => Jon Doe
                    [date] => 2016-03-25 09:27:33
                    [time] => 11:22:00
                    [operationtime] => 1800
                    [groupdate] => 2016-03-25
                    [usetime] => 1800
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [key] => 5BTIB4EoklT6dVfTUR4ezwb8T3xdeTAi
                    [machineid] => HIT232300
                    [empCode] => 1004
                    [employeeid] => Jon Doe
                    [date] => 2016-03-25 09:27:33
                    [time] => 11:22:00
                    [operationtime] => 1800
                    [groupdate] => 2016-03-25
                    [usetime] => 1800
                )

        )

)
```

I'm trying to handle using this code using in_array  but that code not working

```
  foreach ($workingLogs as $key => $date) {
          if(in_array($date['groupdate']) = $date['groupdate']){
            $datewise[$date['groupdate']]=$date;
          }else{
            $datewise[]=$date;
          }
```

Currently my table look like ..
[image]

I want look like.
[image]

Please help

Comment: It just seems like you need to make a minor adjustment to your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code... You have to check the if statement with "==". Also, the in_array only returns a boolean. You can't compare it with a non boolean value

```
 foreach ($workingLogs as $key => $date) {
   if(array_key_exists('groupdate', $date) ){
     $datewise[$date['groupdate']]=$date;
   }else{
     $datewise[]=$date;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shimu ,there is some mistake with in_array ,in_array should be 2 parameter .

Comment: Sorry, you are right... But, you want to chech if the key exists right? Then you should use the function array_key_exists. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply using PHP code like this:

PSUEDO CODE:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = fetch results) {
 $elem = array(); 
 $elem['id'] = $row->id;
 $elem['key'] = $row->key;
 $elem['machineid'] = $row->machineid;
 $elem['empCode'] = $row->empCode;
 $elem['employeeid'] = $row->employeeid;
 $elem['date'] = $row->date;
 $elem['time'] = $row->time;
 $elem['operationtime'] = $row->operationtime;
 $elem['groupdate'] = $row->groupdate;
 $elem['usetime'] = $row->usetime;
 $arr['groupdate'][] = $elem;
}
```

And while displaying results, use `groupdate` as key and other fields as values like this:

```
if (! empty($arr)) {
 foreach ($arr as $groupdate => $elem) {
   echo $groupdate;
   if (! empty($elem)) {
    foreach ($elem as $field => $val) {
      // Show records under this groupdate
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: hi Pupil ,thanks ,but that code not  produce exact result , and i'm confused how to use them

Comment: Paste the actual code in your question. I may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include_once('connect.php');
{
    error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE ); 
                $querys="select date from logusages";
                $result=mysqli_query($con,$querys);
   while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))){
             $cart = $row;
 }      
        // mysqli_free_result($result);
}
     $select="select * from logusages";
     $results = mysqli_query($con, $select);
    if(mysqli_num_rows ($results) > 0)
    { 
        $cart = $row;
      while(list($id,$name,$date) = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM))
       {
                  $j=1;   
            $cart[$date][] = array(
           'id' => $id, 
           'name' => $name);
            $j++;
       }
       echo json_encode($cart). "\n";
    }      
       ?>
```

I just passed id and name inside the date, you can pass as per your row values.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($workingLogs as $key => $date) 
{

    $datetime = date("Y-m-d",$date['groupdate']);

    if(isset($newArray[$datetime]))
    {
        $newArray[$datetime][] = $date; 
    }   
    else
    {
        $newArray[$datetime] = $date;   
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Brijal , its display blank array